# Can you tag someone in a git commit message?

Tags: git

Occasionally I would like to call people out in my git commit messages. And also it would let people know they should look at the commit.

Example: "Fix issues caused by +JoeSchmoe"

Comment: I think you could just do what you're doing and have people search for strings like "+XYZ". It doesn't seem like it would add much to have an explicit tagging system.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from doing so. You could also implement a server side hook to act on certain commit messages. I'm not really sure what is asked here though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How you do this depends on how you use Git. There is no built in way to do this within Git, since Git doesn't do any kind of notification.

One option would be to simply set up your own convention, and use your own scripts to extract such commits or send the appropriate notifications in something like a [`post-receive` hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

However, there are existing conventions for how this works in two common Git based workflows: patches sent via email, and GitHub.

In the patches sent via email workflow, used by the Linux kernel and Git project itself, what you do is add lines at the end of the message of the form:

```
Cc: Joe Schmoe <joe.schmoe@example.com>
```

Then when you use [`git format-patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) and [`git send-email`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email) to format and send your patches via email, Joe Schmoe will be CC'd on the email that is sent out, so should be notified via email about this patch.

The other convention, if you use something like GitHub, is to use an `@JoeSchmoe` mention of their GitHub username. I do not know off the top of my head, and their help does not specify, whether this works from the commit message itself; but at the very least, in any comment or pull request you make, you can write `@JoeSchmoe` and he will be notified of the fact that you mentioned him.

Answer (score 8):

I've tried github for this, yes, it works.
when you type @mention in commit message, then you can click the name to navigate to the guy's profile

Answer (score 0):

Git commit messages are free-form but there is no functionality to support anything like this in Git itself.  You could look for a Git wrapper which supports this (Github? No idea) or build something yourself for your local use.